# CakePHP 3 - Deleting associated data using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Posts can have multiple authors.

I want to add the possibility to delete authors in a post using Ajax.

**PostsAuthorsTable.php**

```
$this->belongsTo('Users', [
    'className' => 'Users',
    'foreignKey'    => 'user_id',
    'joinType' => 'INNER'
]);
```

**PostsTable.php**

```
$this->hasMany('PostsAuthors', [ 'foreignKey' => 'post_id' ]);
```

**PostsController.php**

```
public function delete_author($authorID)
{
    $id = $_GET['authorID'];
    $this->Posts->PostsAuthors->delete($id);
    $this->autoRender = false;
}
```

**View: Posts > edit.ctp (JavaScript part)**

```
<?php $this->start('script'); ?>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () { 
        $('.delete-author').on('click', function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '<?= $this->Url->build(["action" => "delete_author"]) ?>',
                type: 'GET',
                data: { authorID: $(this).data('id') }
            });

            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
<?php $this->end(); ?>
```

**View: Posts > edit.ctp (HTML part)**

```
<?php foreach ($post_authors as $post_author): ?>
<tr>
    <td><?= $post_author->user->name ?></td>
    <td class="text-center">
        <a href="#" class="delete-author text-danger" data-id="<?= $post_author->id ?>">
            <i class="icon-trash"></i>
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Thank you for your help. :)

Comment: Hey, why you don't use Cake\View\Helper\FormHelper::postLink

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

**PostsController.php**

```
public function delete_author($authorID)
{
    $id = $_GET['authorID'];
    $entity = $this->Posts->PostsAuthors->get($id);
    $this->Posts->PostsAuthors->delete($entity);
    $this->autoRender = false;
}
```

Comment: A maybe more modern version of AJAX "delete" in pagination tables is shown [here](https://sandbox.dereuromark.de/sandbox/ajax-examples/table) via [Ajax plugin](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-ajax/releases/tag/1.4.0).